# How can i add html and css to my kivy app project?

Tags: python, html, css, kivy

please how can i add Html and css sent to me from a friend..it consist of login page..i want to add  it to my kivy project by collecting data from users input and save them so it can navigate to the next page..and also allow them to login when they whenever they enter this data..... please any help on that?

Comment: do you have other functionality in kivy or are you trying to make the whole thing in html? AFAIK kivy doesn't even have a webview widget

Comment: @Tenacious B i think  kivy have other functionality that can do same thing as html called " kivy language"..but i want to use html and css